# Text alignment design with elipsis using html and css

Tags: html, css

[Example Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKu2I.png)

There are two scenario(Note:Same Html and css should work for the both scenario)

1) When i have less text then that text has to fit in the  middle of div with responsive .

2) when i have a large text then that has to start from the beginning of the div and ellipsis for the third line but should be responsive.

Comment: Where is the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  display: block;
  /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 109.2px;
  /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Ref: http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work for the both the Scenario